# Php inside HTML that's inside PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

I've been doing the following html/php code to print an image:

```
<img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/image-path" height="200" width="200" />
```

however, now I need to change this to a loop where I echo the html with php inside, like this

```
foreach($urls as $views){
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<img src="Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . $views" height="200" width="200" />'; //problematic line
        echo '<h3>' ;
        echo Html::a("Heading",array("/site/textpost"));
        echo '</h3>';
        echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
```

and I can't seem to find a way to make the Yii:$app request work, since it's php inside the html that's already inside php code.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't place it "_inside the HTML_" then: `echo '<img src="' . Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . $views . '" height="200" width="200" />';`

Answer (score 1):

I would do a simple variable to store the image url and then concatenate it like this :

```
foreach($urls as $views){
  $imgUrl = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . $views;
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<img src="' . $imgUrl . '" height="200" width="200" />';
  echo '<h3>' ;
  echo Html::a("Heading",array("/site/textpost"));
  echo '</h3>';
  echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>';
  echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: `$imgUrl` wouldn't be parsed/resolved though since you echo using single quotes `'`

Comment: You right kerbh0lz, I totally forgot that. I just modified my anwser, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using a single quote, non-interpolated string.

If you change that to be a double quoted string, it should work just fine:

```
foreach($urls as $views){
    echo '<li>';
    echo "<img src='{Yii::$app->request->baseUrl}{$views}' height='200' width='200' />"; //problematic line
    echo '<h3>' ;
    echo Html::a("Heading",array("/site/textpost"));
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

As noted, you can simply remove the "inner PHP" so it's not within the HTML string by concatenating elements together.

Another option is to use heredoc syntax, eg:

```
$heading = Html::a("Heading", array("/site/textpost"));

foreach ($urls as $views) {

    $imgSrc = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . $views;

    echo <<<OUTPUT
<li>
    <img src="{$imgSrc}" height="200" width="200" />
    <h3>{$heading}</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</li>
OUTPUT;
}
```